# Como selecciono un hijo(input) de un item hermano(span -button) en jquery creado por codigo dinamico

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, phpmyadmin

estoy haciendo un ecommerce como proyecto personal y traigo de la base de datos de forma dinamica los productos por jquery, pero tengo en un input tipo number con la cantidad de de productos que el usuario quiere comprar el boton es un elemento hermano(el span )que es el padre del input pero si el usuario no especifica el valor trae el valor del primer input y no del input cuyo padre (span) es hermano del boton.

Esto es un ejemplo del codigo que genera los productos dinamicamente
yo quiero seleccionar solamente el input dentro del span al que el cliente hace click.

```
  <div id='container'>

  </div>


    <script type="text/javascript">

      $(document).ready(function (e) {  
      var amountofproducts=8;
      $.ajax({
        type:"Post",
        url:"custom.php",
        dataType:"json",
        success:function(){
          addproducts();
        }

      });
      function addproducts(){
          for (let index = 0; index < amountofproducts; index++) {
            $('#container').append(
              `
               <div class='item' id='item'>     
       <span class='span-name'>Nombre: </span><br>
       <span class='span-price'>Price: some price</span><br>
       <span class='span-cant'>Quantity: <input class='spa' type='number' maxlength='2'   name='cantidad' min='1' max='10' value='1' step='1' > </input></span><br>
       <br><button type='text'   class='btn-item'>Buy</button>
       </div>
              `
            );
    $(document).on('click', '.btn-item', function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      addproducts();
    });

var can=1;
$(document).on('change','span>input',function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  if($(event.target).val()<=10){    
    can=$(event.target).val();
    $('.spa').html($(this).val());

  }
  
  else if($(event.target).val()>10){

     $('.spa').html($(this).val(1));
     //alert("La cantidad ingresada supera la disponible.");
  }

  });
          }
        }

      });

    </script>
```

Ejemplo de codigo en custom:

```
<?php
echo json_encode(array());
?>
```

Comment: Debes agregar un [MCVE]. Por ejemplo tu pregunta no tiene relación con PHP, por lo que no debería haber código en dicho lenguaje. Yo debo poder copiar tu código y reproducir el problema fácilmente. Y por último en tu código no hay ningún botón que sea hermano de algún input

Comment: Ya he corrigido y agregado un ejemplo minimo verificable, si me equivoque lo que quiero hacer es traer el valor del input hijo del span que es hermano del button.

Comment: _y traigo de la base de datos de forma dinamica los productos por jquery_ todavia tengo mi duda sobre como jquery se conecta a la base de datos... juraba que jquery funciona en el frontend con html y no en el backend con mysql ... estas 100% seguro que Jquery es quien trae la informacion de la base de datos y no PHP????

Comment: primero debes hacer la seleccion del `padre estatito` ya que utilizas `document` y esto es muy pesado, porque estas leyendo todo el documento nuevamente... para seleccionar el hermano puedes usar el selector avanzado de hermano `+` ejemplo: `$('h1 + span')`  esto buscara los `span` que tengan antes un hermano mayor `h1`

Comment: Se que el php trae el codigo(por ahi lo redacte mal porque lo edite) pero el problema esta en el jquery  y como el problema esta ahi simplifique el codigo porque no estoy pudiendo seleccionar el input dentro del span que es hermano del button una vez que el evento click se ejecuta en un determinado boton seleccione al span y traiga el valor del hijo de ese span osea el input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para seleccionar el `input` (cuya clase es `spa`) que corresponde al mismo `item` del botón tienes que ir al padre y de ahí buscar el `input`

Solo con javascript

```
const input = event.target.parentElement.querySelector("input.spa");
```

Con jQuery

```
const input = $(event.target).parent().find("input.spa");
```

Comment: Gracias amigo yussef por tu aporte. Eso soluciono el problema.